# How can I find out what's wrong with a bugreport file

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, battery

I have generated a bugreport.txt using `adb bugreport > bugreport.txt`. When I upload it to battery historian I get the error message:

> bugreport.txt does not contain a valid bugreport file

How can I find out what's wrong with the file? I use android 6.0 and battery historian 3.0 with docker.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're using PowerShell to generate the bugreport.txt file. Sadly, Battery Historian cannot handle TXT files with UTF-16 encoding, which is the default for PowerShell.

You have several options to create TXT files with UTF-8 encoding on Windows:

1. Change the encoding of the previously created UTF-16 file to UTF-8. For example, by opening the file in Notepad++, change the Encoding in the top menu and save the file.
2. Use the Windows Command Prompt (CMD) instead.
3. Change the default encoding of PowerShell. A quick internet search should be able to help you with that.

Another possible issue could be that d3 was not defined, but that bug is not limited to Android 5 and 6. For more information: https://dreambyte.nl/2021/01/04/adventures-in-using-android-battery-historian/